# Can not fetch the updating data from CoreData after saving

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I refer the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html) to save data to CoreData, and My codegen of Entity is Category/Extension([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e94Fa.png))

I use the performBackgroundTask to save the data.
While, I can not fetch the data after saving.
I have to force close an app and then reopen it again, and the I can fetch the saving data.

The followings are my code.

The method to save the data to CoreData:

```
var container: NSPersistentContainer? =
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer

private func updateDatabase() {

    container?.performBackgroundTask { [weak self] context in

        if let name = self?.employeeName.text {
            _ = try? Employee.findOrCreateEmployee(matching: name, in: context)
        }

        var date = (self?.startDate)!
        let end = (self?.endDate)!

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "MM/dd"

        while date <= end {
            //print(fmt.string(from: date))

            _ = try? Shift.findOrCreateShift(byEmployee: (self?.employeeName1.text)!, date: fmt.string(from: date), assignment: nil, in: context)
            date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
        }

        try? context.save()
    }
}
```

The method to fetch the data from CoreData:

```
var container: NSPersistentContainer? =
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer {
    didSet { updateUI() }
}

private func updateUI() {
    if let context = container?.viewContext {
        let employeeRequest: NSFetchRequest<Employee> = Employee.fetchRequest()
        employeeRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(
            key: "created",
            ascending: true,
            )]
        employees = try? context.fetch(employeeRequest)

        let shiftsRequest: NSFetchRequest<Shift> = Shift.fetchRequest()
        shiftsRequest.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(
            key: "date",
            ascending:true
            )]
        shifts = try? context.fetch(shiftsRequest)

    }
}
```

Does anyone has any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: in your persistentContainer setup did you set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` property of the `viewContext` to true?

Comment: @JonRose Thanks for your help, set the property to true, and it works.

Comment: @KiritModi, Thanks for your help too